# Check if array of hashes contains hash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

Let's say I have a variable like:

```
var vendors = [
    {
      Name: 'Magenic',
      ID: 'ABC'
     },
    {
      Name: 'Microsoft',
      ID: 'DEF'
    }
];

var v1 = {
      Name: 'Magenic',
      ID: 'ABC'
     };
```

When I run the following code to search for `v1` in `vendors` using **indexOf** it always returns `-1`

```
console.log(vendors.indexOf(v1));
```

Even though `v1` exists in `vendors` array it returns -1. What it the proper way to find the index of an object in array of objects using js?

I can use a loop, but it is costly :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
var vendors = [{ Name: 'Magenic', ID: 'ABC' }, { Name: 'Microsoft', ID: 'DEF' }];

console.log(vendors.findIndex(v => v.ID === 'ABC')) // 0
console.log(vendors.findIndex(v => v.ID === 'DEF')) // 1
```

Comment: It's not returning the index.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is an ES6 feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex and that it is not supported in IE (not that it's just **that** relevant, just wanted to point that out)

Comment: It works! Didn't know about the `findIndex` method. Accepted. :) wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

To check if array contains object you can use `some()` and then check if each `key - value` pair exists in some object of array with `every()`, and this will return `true/false` as result.

```js
var vendors = [{
  Name: 'Magenic',
  ID: 'ABC'
}, {
  Name: 'Microsoft',
  ID: 'DEF'
}];

var v1 = {
  Name: 'Magenic',
  ID: 'ABC'
};

var result = vendors.some(function(e) {
  return Object.keys(v1).every(function(k) {
    if(e.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      return e[k] == v1[k]
    }
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can test if an object is contained in an array of objects

```js
var vendors = [
    {
      Name: 'Magenic',
      ID: 'ABC'
     },
    {
      Name: 'Microsoft',
      ID: 'DEF'
    }
];

var v1 = {
      Name: 'Magenic',
      ID: 'ABC'
     };

var result = vendors.findIndex(x => x.ID === v1.ID && x.Name === v1.Name)
console.log(result);
```